# Passing a URL from SharePoint 2013 list to Power View in Excel 2013

Tags: list, 2013, powerview

I have exported a SharePoint 2013 list to Power View in Excel 2013 and am having problems with the hyperlink passing along to Power View.

This kind of crosses technologies, so I figured I would see if anyone here has run into this.

I've created  the following columns in my SharePoint list and put URLs in all three:

- Single line of text
- Multiple lines of text
- Hyperlink

Power View is rendering these as text strings, instead of active hyperlinks. Is there anything I could be doing different in my SharePoint list to change how the URL is interpreted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was **resolved**. The breakdown was with auto-formatting in Excel. When you export a list from SharePoint to Excel, Excel will auto-format URLs into hyperlinks.

I exported my SharePoint list without any values in the column that the URLs were supposed to go into and was trying to do a data refresh, which is why the hyperlinks were lost.

*To solve*:

- Populate all URLs before exporting to Excel

Or, if you are updating URL values post-export:

- Update URL in SharePoint list (that is already linked to Excel)
- Open the table in Excel that is linked to PowerPivot
- Click on the 'Data' tab on the ribbon
- Click on the 'Refresh All' button on the 'Data' tab (URLs should now be in the Excel table as regular text)
- Click into the cell that contains the new URL value
- Click out of the cell

Excel should auto-format the URL to become a hyperlink once you click out of the cell. If this does not initialize the hyperlink auto-formatting, manually create hyperlinks for all URLs within the Excel table that is linked to PowerPivot. Power View will not interpret URLs as hyperlinks, it only interprets the data types as they are represented in the source data table.

Thanks @DavePaylor for the input

Answer (score 0):

Are you routing this through PowerPivot?  If so then check if there are formatting options in PowerPivot to help.  There is no support for hyperlinks in 2010 but it was added in 2013 - though you seem to be using 2013 so should be OK.

There is a small section on hyperlinks [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/whats-new-in-power-view-in-excel-2013-and-in-sharepoint-server-HA102901475.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't seem like there are data formatting options in PowerPivot aside from : Text, Date, Whole Number, Decimal Number, Currency and True/False. The documentation lists that it is possible, it assumes that hyperlinks just work. My exported sheet in Excel retains the hyperlink, but when it goes into PowerPivot, it is lost - which is probably why Power View just recognizes it as regular text. I am going to try to see if I can isolate the issues between the linked table and PowerPivot.